# How to read an XML document in C# with a namespace that has no associated prefix

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to read OSIS formatted documents.  I have cut the document down to a simple fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<osis xmlns="http://www.bibletechnologies.net/2003/OSIS/namespace">
  <osisText osisRefWork="Bible" osisIDWork="kjv" xml:lang="en">
  </osisText>
</osis>
```

I try to read it with this sample code from the MSDN documentation:

```
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("osis.xml");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select("/osis/osisText");

while (nodes.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(nodes.Current.Name);
}
```

The problem is that the selection contains no nodes and throws no exception.  Since the code discards the root tag, I can't read the document.  If I remove the xmlns="http://www.bibletechnologies.net/2003/OSIS/namespace" from the root osis tag, it works just fine.  The offensive URL returns a 404 code, but otherwise I see nothing wrong with this XML.  Can someone explain why this code won't read the document?  What options do I have besides hand editing every document before trying to load it?

Comment: That XML looks pretty well formed to me. What makes you think it is malformed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your XPath expression is missing a namespace prefix.

The element that you're trying to select has a namespace URI of `http://www.bibletechnologies.net/2003/OSIS/namespace`, and XPath *will not match* these nodes using paths with an empty namespace URI.

I tested this revision in .NET 2.0 and it found the node as expected.

```
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("osis.xml");
XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

XmlNamespaceManager xmlns = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
xmlns.AddNamespace("osis", "http://www.bibletechnologies.net/2003/OSIS/namespace");

XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select("/osis:osis/osis:osisText", xmlns);
```

Comment: XML is pretty simple until you add namespaces.  The actual osis node is:<osis xmlns="http://www.bibletechnologies.net/2003/OSIS/namespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bibletechnologies.net/2003/OSIS/namespace http://www.bibletechnologies.net/osisCore.2.1.1.xsd">.  Do I need to add something else to the namespace manager?

Comment: @JEdwardEllis, no... and I overlooked that you already had created a navigator.  Yeah, you have to get into the zen of namespaces to minimize frustration.  It can be ugly sometimes, but I learned from dealing with EPUBs (which use multiple namespaces) that you can't fight it.  Good luck.

Comment: Is there a good resource for learning about XML namespaces?  I hate stumbling around in the dark.

Comment: If you're using .NET, the framework documentation is actually pretty good, especially since it's usually geared towards usage in applications.  I read [XML in a Nutshell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596000585.do) in 2004 or so, and much of it still holds true (certainly the parts about namespaces, anyway).  The [zvon tutorial](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html) is still a good starting reference for XPath.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file to a string, replace the namespace in memory, and then load it using a string stream:

```
string s;
using(var reader = File.OpenText("osis.xml"))
{
    s = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
s = s.Replace("xmlns=\"http://www.bibletechnologies.net/2003/OSIS/namespace\"", "");
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s));
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("stream");
// Rest of the code
```

Comment: -1: as with most cases of pretending that XML is just a string format, this fails. What if, instead, the document said `xmlns:x="http://www.bibletechnologies.net/2003/OSIS/namespace"`? What if it used "y" as a prefix? What if there were multiple namespace declarations, for the same namespace, but with different prefixes?

Comment: @JohnSaunders did you find an answer?